# Write bitmap messed up with horizontal lines

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, paint, porter-duff

I am attempting to finger draw on a transparent bitmap. The canvas Im using draws the image just fine, but when I save the image, the image shows like below, with all the horizontal transparent lines.

[image: Saved Image]

I draw using the following code.

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    mOffScreenCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    for(int index = 0; index < mAnnotations.size(); index++) {
        InkAnnotation annotation = mAnnotations.get(index);

        annotation.draw(mOffScreenCanvas, ActivityPageToolBar.mCurrentTool.paint());
    }

    if(canvas != null && mSurface != null) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mSurface, 0, 0, mPaint);
    }
}
```

The file is saved using

```
            Bitmap saveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(map);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(saveBitmap);
            c.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            c.drawBitmap(map,0,0,null);
```

i use standard file saving to save it

```
try {
              FileOutputStream out = handle.outputStream();

              if(handle.fileName().contains(".png")) {
                  ((Bitmap) handle.data()).compress(CompressFormat.PNG, quality, out);
              } else if(handle.fileName().contains(".jpg") || handle.fileName().contains(".jpeg")) {
                  ((Bitmap) handle.data()).compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);
              } else {
                  ((Bitmap) handle.data()).compress(CompressFormat.WEBP, quality, out);
              }
              out.flush();
              out.close();
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Any way to fix this issue? At the same time I am embedding the bitmap into a pdf and the colors are darker than they should be.

This is what the image looks like on the screen before I save it. The background is irrelevant, i can draw to the screen just fine, but when it save it to a png it looks messed up.

[image]

Comment: Sorry don't understand what is wrong. Please post a picture of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by taking the points I created on the surfaceview and creating a new bitmap from those points. There must be something the surface it doing to its bitmap to cause this.